# Magento 2: Hide price from the upsell and related products block

Tags: magento2, price, related-products, up-sells, hide

I want to hide price from the related products and the upsell products block

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are using version 2.4.0.

The file below is responsible for rendering those lists: related, upsell, cross-sell, etc.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

The easiest way to hide the price is to overwrite it on your theme.

```
app/design/Mechanic/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/list/items.phtml
```

You can simply copy and paste the content of the core file to the file above that you must be created and then remove line 226:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml#L226